# TableLogger.cs Throwing Storageexception 409 conflict

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-table-storage

Hi guys im using  [TableLogger.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableLogger.cs) implementation to log conversation history to azure table storage. At first fire on my bot emulator it will run smoothly but after you stop it and do a rerun, It will encounters a storageexception 409 conflict error.

TableLogger.cs:
[image]

Inner Exception:
[image]

im confused, 409 conflict error occurs if table already exists, whats the purpose of the createifnotexists method if it cant handle such case? how can i resolve this? thanks

im using this code on my global.asax to save both botdata and conversation history of the user and the bot, it uses tablelogger.cs implementation.

Global Asax:

```
  var tableName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TableName"].ToString();
        var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        //Azure StateData
        Conversation.UpdateContainer(
            builder =>
            {
                //azure botdata
                builder.RegisterModule(new AzureModule(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
                var store = new TableBotDataStore(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                builder.Register(c => store)
                   .Keyed<IBotDataStore<BotData>>(AzureModule.Key_DataStore)
                   .AsSelf()
                   .SingleInstance();
                //azure conversation history
                account.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(tableName).DeleteIfExists();
                builder.RegisterModule(new TableLoggerModule(account, tableName));
            });
```

Comment: 409 is usually access denied error, you will get error in cases like key/secret is wrong or you computer time is off by few seconds that will lead to mismatch signatures.

Comment: added an inner exception error for more details about the error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918898/azure-table-duplicate-partition-key-results-in-409-conflict